# SimpleDateFormat parsing to date more than it should?

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have an arrayList here

```
list.add(new Release(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString));

setAlerts();
```

Here is the method i am using to get the size of the list and parse the dates.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    Release eDate = new Release(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString);
    String reDate = eDate.getReleaseDate();
    String nameOf = eDate.getName();
    if(reDate.contains(",")){
        Date dateParsed = null;
        try {
            dateParsed = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy").parse(reDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String dateFormated = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dateParsed);
    }
}
```

This method parses the same date more than once.. it is only 13 items in the list, and it parses WAY more.

Is it anyway i can change the method to correct this?

It also only returning the dates for the last couple of items in the list. not all.

Comment: Is it possible to give the complete method for the the function that you mentioned above? Are you calling this method in more than one place?

Comment: Whcich method setAlerts()? If so, the method with for() is the setAlert() method. And i only call it in above after the arraylist is set

Comment: What I mean, a full method body and not the partial one. Otherwise it is hard to see what's going on

Comment: That is the full method.

Comment: It sits the list.add() and after that calls the setAlert() method, which is below it.

Answer (score 0):

You loop over a list, so if your list really contains only 13 elements, you are calling the method multiple times (after each `list.add(..)`?)

Also, you are looping over a list, but you are not doing anything with the list itself .. don't you need to retrieve the elements from your list and do something with them (`Release release = (Release) list.get(i)`) .. why else would you loop over a list?

Have you tried debugging your app?